# Лі́карський чи Ліка́рський? Як правильно?

Tags: значення-слів, наголос

З наголосом в словах За́мок і Замо́к все зрозуміло ще зі школи, а ось Лі́карський чи Ліка́рський не зовсім.  Як правильно?

Answer (score 5):

Я тривалий час вважала, що немає значення як саме поставити наголос в слові ***Лікарський***, а виявилось не правильно. Різний наголос і відповідно різне значення слів.

*Лі́карський* - халат, обхід, таємниця, дільниця, рецепт, клятва.

*Ліка́рський* - рослини, трави, препарати, ягоди.

Зокрема  на сайті ["Як ми говоримо"](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/likarskyj-likuvalnyj-likarnyanyj-likarskyj) дають наступне пояснення:

> Прикметник ***лі́карський*** означає «належний лікареві» (*лі́карський* халат)
> або «такий, що стосується діяльності лікаря» (лі́карський огляд);
> *«Хора лежала непритомна, і здавалося, що не чула **лі́карської** гадки»*
> (І. Франко).
> Прикметник ***лікува́льний*** указує на оздоровчі, збудливі,
> тамівні властивості, цебто має зв’язок із поняттями ліки, лікувати:
> *«Виноград має і **лікува́льні** властивості»* («Колгоспна виробнича
> енциклопедія»).

У [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/likarsjkyj) можемо побачити приклади використання цих слів:

> *Хо слухає, як молодий лікар розгортає плани своєї **лі́карської** та просвітньої діяльності на селі* (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 172)
>
> *Лубенщина — один з найважливіших центрів культури і збору **ліка́рських** рослин на Україні* (Труди ботанічного саду АН УРСР, 1, 1949, 50).

Не припускайтеся моїх помилок. Говоріть правильно!

Comment: _Лі́карський_ – який стосується лікаря, належить лікареві, пов'язаний з лікуванням: _лі́карська порада, лі́карський халат, лі́карська дільниця_. _Ліка́рський_ – який має лікувальні властивості: _ліка́рські рослини_. (Словник труднощів української мови: Біля 15 000 слів/ За ред.С.Я.Єрмоленко, К.:Радянська школа, 1989)